# How can I prove that is A is a m by n matrix and m<n, then there exist distinct vectors x and y such that Ax=Ay?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, vectors

If I reduce A to reduced echelon form, then it has fewer pivots than columns (since mx and **y** that satisfy A**x**=A**y**?

Answer (score 0):

Going backwards, we can get the answer:

Subtracting $A\vec{y}$ from both sides and factoring gives $A(\vec{x}-\vec{y}) = \vec{0}$.

As we know that $\vec{x} \ne \vec{y}$, we know that the quantity $(\vec{x}-\vec{y})$ is not $\vec{0}$, and therefore the equation $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ has a non-trivial solution. From this we know that $A$ is LD, meaning that there are free variables. As there are free variables there must be columns without pivots. As you already pointed out, there are, so we are done.